# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to write a script that will fill database from json file. It looks like this:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        categories = load_from_json('categories')

        ProductCategory.objects.all().delete()
        for category in categories:
            new_category = ProductCategory(**category)
            new_category.save()

        restaurants = load_from_json('restaurants')

        Restaurant.objects.all().delete()
        for restaurant in restaurants:
            category_name = restaurant['category']
            _category = ProductCategory.objects.get(name=category_name)
            restaurant['category'] = _category
            new_restaurant = Restaurant(**restaurant)
            new_restaurant.save()
```

When i run it, django throws an error: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use category.set() instead.
My models looks like this:

```py
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='наименование категории', max_length=64, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_images', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='описание категории', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='наименование ресторана', max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='описание категории', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='restaurant_images', blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Looks like many people have encountered with this problem, but i struggle with finding a solution to this.

Comment: Did you try to follow Django advice? Remove `restaurant['category'] = _category` from your code and add `new_restaurant.category.set(_category)` instead

Comment: not quite sure how to make it. what should i put in ```new_restaraunt``` variable?

Comment: Take your code, delete the line `restaurant['category']  = ...` then add the line `new_restaurant.category.set(...)` after the line `new_restaurant = Restaurant(**restaurant)`.

Comment: tried your suggestion, still doesnt work. same error